# Tkinter in Python, enumerate

Tags: python, list, loops, tkinter, enumerate

I need your help. I want to make a few labels. After clicked, the number on every label should change to a text accordiong to the number. I tried this, but it just changes the text on every label to the last item in the list2. What should I do to make it change accordingly? Numbers and texts are on the same position in both lists.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

list1 = [["one", "two", "three", "four"], ["five", "six", "seven", "eight"],["nine","ten","eleven","twelve"]]
list2 = [["1","2","3","4"], ["5", "6", "7", "8"],["9", "10", "11", "12"]]

def change_label(event):
    for row, rowinlist in enumerate(list2):
        for column, text2 in enumerate(rowinlist):    
            event.widget.configure(text=text2)

for row, rowinlist in enumerate(list1):
    for column, text in enumerate(rowinlist):
        label = tk.Label(text=text, width=15, bd=1, relief="raised")
        label.grid(row=row, column=column)
        label.bind("<1>", change_label)
        x = text

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***"the number on every label should change to a text "***:As it stands this couldn't be the case as you are looping `list1` which is `[["one", "two",...`. Do `print(widget.grid_info())` ans see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you go through all the items in `list2` and set the text of `event.widget` to it, so the final result is the last item of `list2`.

You need to save the `row` and `column` of each label and use them to set its text:

```
def change_label(event):
    row, col = event.widget.pos # get the position of clicked label
    event.widget.configure(text=list2[row][col])

for row, rowinlist in enumerate(list1):
    for column, text in enumerate(rowinlist):
        label = tk.Label(text=text, width=15, bd=1, relief="raised")
        label.grid(row=row, column=column)
        label.bind("<1>", change_label)
        label.pos = (row, column) # save the position of label
```